# Remote alert (Pager) system using React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a 'pager' type app with React Native that needs to alert users (with an alarm) when a status flag is changed from open to closed from a remote web app.

I have been using a polling system to ping the web app however this is ineffectual when the app is in the background or the phone is locked.

I have looked at using a push notification system like One Signal to push notifications to the app. However i need to also set off an alarm as well.

They app will need to work in both iOs and Android. Currently I am only developing in iOS. Any suggestions on the best approach for such and app?

Comment: Push notification is what you need, but you have to add all logic about turning on/off alarm, but i think you are in the correct way with push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

As [Facundo La Rocca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585153/facundo-la-rocca) mentioned before you should use a push notifications to handle communication between web app and end user. The push notification can contain a payload which you can use further to perform certain action in your app e.g. toggle an alarm or something. PushWoosh seems okay, I've used it couple of times.